# mathematics of spatial diffusion models

Tags: spatial-statistics, mathematics

There are different types of spatial diffusion such as contagious model, migration model, etc.  What are the good books to learn about the mathematics behind these spatial diffusion models?

Answer (score 3):

Diffusion models are a class of (partial) differential equations.  Finding a textbook that is clear to you will be a huge head start.  I can't offer any titles, though.  If you're already comfortable with differentials, then the standard reference Wikipedia provides (Crank, J. (1956). The Mathematics of Diffusion. Oxford: Clarendon Press) will be as good as anything.

If you're looking for how to program models, it might be amusing to remember that Conway's original 'Game of Life' program is a diffusion exercise in vast simplification. Good luck!